# What do the "subsystem,windows" options do in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc

I've looked at the man pages for gcc, but still cant find doc on what the "subsystem,windows" options do, as in:

```
g++.exe foo.o ... -Wl,-subsystem,windows
```

I'm running only in Windows, and linking C++ code. I can guess maybe what "windows" is, but would like to see some documentation.

Comment: It's the GCC equivalent to the [`/SUBSYSTEM` MSVC option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem). In this case it specifies the "WINDOWS" subsystem, which mostly means it does not need a console.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it makes it so that when you double click the program from windows explorer, it doesn't show the console, convenient for right click utilities and windowed applications that don't want a console to show(at the start at least).

Comment: `-Wl` means "pass the following comma-spearated words to the linker". This means, the linker sees `-subsystem windows`, and you must look up the meaning of this in the manual of the linker (not necessarily gcc).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you contributors. With your help I was able to figure this out. In my case,
`-subsystem,windows` tells `ld` to not open a "Console". In my case, the "Console" is where my C `printf()` commands come out.

So actually this is a terrible option for debugging!

Answer (score 0):

These are the so-called subsystems, on which your instructions execute. Most compilers (atleast on Windows) include `Console`, `Windows`, `Native`, `EFI-Application`, `EFI-Boot-Service-Driver`, `EFI-ROM`, `EFI-Runtime-Driver`, and `Posix`.

You can also quickly set the subsytem to Windows by adding the flag `-mwindows` in gcc.
(The `Windows` subsystem is recognized as a standalone application by the kernel and won't execute in a console or dos window)